# Sound output changing automatically

Tags: audio

I'm trying to solve this problem for days. When I'm listening loud(around 100%) music, system is changing output device from Analog Output to Headphones output. Headphones output is not even available if I'm not listening to music. It only appears when system change to it and back to analog. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.